# Interactive Brokers - EWrapperImpl Example - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

Why is the code below throwing the Object reference error when it tries to use the ClientSocket?

I copied this example from the Interactive Brokers API documentation.

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm

I am connected using the IB Gateway.

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041

I have seen the following post, but it is still not clear what I am doing wrong here.

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Throws the error on the myClient.ClientSocket line:

```
var myClient = new EWrapperImpl();

myClient.ClientSocket.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0);
```

Here is the wrapper class:

```
public class EWrapperImpl : EWrapper
{
    EClientSocket clientSocket;

    public EWrapperImpl()
    {
        clientSocket = new EClientSocket(this);
    }

    public EClientSocket ClientSocket { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you initialize the **private** field `clientSocket` (with a lower-case 'c') in your constructor, but access a public field or property `ClientSocket` (with an upper-case 'C').
So, you are initializing a field that gets never used and try to access a property that is never initialized.

The easiest way to fix your code is to remove the private field and to initialize the property instead:

```
public class EWrapperImpl : EWrapper
{
    public EWrapperImpl()
    {
        ClientSocket = new EClientSocket(this);
    }

    public EClientSocket ClientSocket { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that line of code was omitted for brevity. I added it to the post. public EClientSocket ClientSocket { get; set; }

Comment: I think the real problem is that the program cannot tell that the IB Gateway is connected. But, I will try your edits.

Comment: That did fix the null reference error. Why would the documentation be so wrong?

Comment: @ADH: The documentation is correct. But you didn't copy that code exactly. Your property is an auto-property. Their property is using the private field. There is your error.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Thank you.